# change Default Tab in MDBottomNavigation of kivymd

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivy-language

Friends i have very brief question:
How i can change the **default Tab** in MD Bottom Navigation?
is this MD Bottom Navigation is the same as Tabbed Panel in kivy?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I think the solution is to use `first_widget` as documented here: https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottom-navigation/#kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigation.first_widget

Note that you need to pass the actual `MDBottomNavigationItem` here so that you cannot set the default tab from KvLang. You need to set the `first_widget` programmatically or use the `switch_tab` method which makes more sense at this point. See https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottom-navigation/#kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigation.switch_tab